# Convert Multiple Json Array to a Single Array Rather than Array Inside a Parent Array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have Following 2 Json in 2 rows.

```
  {
            "attributes": [{
                "name": "text-1580797977710",
                "value": "Nikesh Niroula"
            }, {
                "name": "email-1580797979166",
                "value": "nikesh@gmail.com"
            }]
          }


{
    "attributes": [{
            "name": "text-1580797977720",
            "value": "Denver"
        }, {
            "name": "text-1580797977723",
            "value": "colarado"
        },
        {
            "name": "text-1580797977727",
            "value": "USA"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need the above json to be aggregated into one single array by using postgresql, the expected result would be as below. I tried using json_agg but this will add a inner array inside the main array. There might be multiple json and not only 2.

```
  {
        "attributes": [{
                "name": "text-1580797977710",
                "value": "Nikesh Niroula"
            }, {
                "name": "email-1580797979166",
                "value": "nikesh@gmail.com"
            }, {
                "name": "text-1580797977720",
                "value": "Denver"
            }, {
                "name": "text-1580797977723",
                "value": "colarado"
            },
            {
                "name": "text-1580797977727",
                "value": "USA"
            }
        ]

     }
```

Comment: Should this work with any number of rows, or just two values?

Comment: any number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
the concatenation operator (`||`) along with `jsonb_array_elements` `jsonb_agg` functions to solve your problem.

```
with t (id,
attr1,
attr2) as (
values (1,
'{
      "attributes": [
        {
          "name": "one-1",
          "value": "Nikesh Niroula"
        }]}'::jsonb,
'{"attributes": [
        {
          "name": "one-2",
          "value": "Nikesh Niroula"
        }]}'::jsonb) ,
(1,
'{
      "attributes": [
        {
          "name": "two-1",
          "value": "Nikesh Niroula"
        }]}'::jsonb,
'{"attributes": [
        {
          "name": "two-2",
          "value": "Nikesh Niroula"
        }]}'::jsonb) ,
(1,
'{
      "attributes": [
        {
          "name": "three-1",
          "value": "Nikesh Niroula"
        }]}'::jsonb,
'{"attributes": [
        {
          "name": "three-2",
          "value": "Nikesh Niroula"
        }]}'::jsonb) ,
(2,
'{
      "attributes": [
        {
          "name": "four-1",
          "value": "Nikesh Niroula"
        }]}'::jsonb,
'{"attributes": [
        {
          "name": "four-2",
          "value": "Nikesh Niroula"
        }]}'::jsonb) )
select
    id ,
    jsonb_agg(value)
from
    t,
    jsonb_array_elements(attr1->'attributes' ||(attr2->'attributes'))
group by
    1;
```

Comment: i will have undefined number of rows - i mean not just 2 rows

Comment: just saw @jjanes's answer,  uses `jsonb_array_elements `.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unnest them before you feed them to the agg function.  If the table is "j" and the column is "x", then:

```
select jsonb_build_object('attributes',jsonb_agg(value))
   from j, jsonb_array_elements(x->'attributes');
```